# mapsuscirber, how to access to component variables?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

I have a form, and I control changes with a suscription:

```
<form #f="ngForm">

  <mat-card-content>

    <mat-input-container>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="id" name="id" placeholder="id" (ngModelChange)="elementChanged$.next($event)"/>
      </mat-input-container>
   </mat-card-content>

</form>
export class myComponent implements OnInit {

 dataToGet: string;
 formChanged$: Observable<boolean>;
 elementChanged$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
 elementSubscription: Subscription;

 constructor() {

   this.elementSubscription = this.elementChanged$  
     .debounceTime(500)
     .map(this.formHaveChanged)
     .subscribe(haveChanged => this.formChanged$ = haveChanged)
  }

  formHaveChanged(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.dataToGet -> fails because of this is mapSuscriber
    return Observable.of(true)
  }
}
```

So my problem is clear, when I'm inside formHaveChanged() function "this" is mapSuscriber instead of myComponent, I need to access mycomponent variables, but I cant get it, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.map(this.formHaveChanged.bind(this))
```

or

```
.map(() => this.formHaveChanged())
```

`this.formHaveChanged` is unbound function. You don't have access to this in unbound functions.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I need